# Performace degradation when starting many Docker containers

Tags: linux, sockets, parallel-processing, docker

I built a web application that provides a web-based programming environment for beginners. Users' code is executed in Docker containers. The application is based on Rails and uses the [docker-api gem](https://github.com/swipely/docker-api) for accessing [Docker's Remote API](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api/).

Although Docker should provide a fairly scalable platform for executing many users' code in parallel, the response times go through the roof when putting load on the application using JMeter.

Neither CPU nor memory seem to be a bottleneck. Using New Relic, I can see that the communication with Docker's socket accounts for 99% of the time spent in the particular controller method ([Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vp1sw.png)). When I try to invoke `docker ps` during the load test, I have to wait for several seconds for the command to return.

An experiment using Docker's CLI shows the same behavior. A couple of long-running computations can be executed in parallel once all containers have been started. In contrast, many short-running computations do not run in parallel, since there seems to be a problem with starting the containers quickly enough.

Is it possible that Docker cannot parallelize starting containers?

Comment: Can you put some numbers on 'response times go through the roof'?  How long, for how many requests/sec ?

Comment: The execution times for running a simple piece of code range from less than a second to about a minute. The throughput is about 49 per minute.

Comment: If it was me I would run `strace` on the Docker daemon and see if it gets stuck for long periods on anything in particular. This requires understanding of Linux system calls.

Comment: I will consider this as a last resort.

Comment: Is it your application that becomes slow or is it the calls to the docker daemon API which are?

Comment: The majority of the time is spent waiting for a POST request to `/var/run/docker.sock` using Excon. As I said, Docker's CLI has a considerable latency, too.